# Adding NSDecimalNumber returning nil

Tags: objective-c, nsdecimalnumber

I have this code

```
int countCosts = [Costs count];
countCosts = countCosts - 1;
NSDecimalNumber* Total = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:[NSString    stringWithFormat:@"%f", 0.0]];
NSDecimalNumber *cost = 0;
    while (countCosts != -1)
    {
        cost = [Costs objectAtIndex:countCosts];
        Total = [Total decimalNumberByAdding:cost];
        countCosts = countCosts - 1;
        if (countCosts < 0)
            break;
    }
```

Costs (Array has 1.10, 2.25, 3.50) in it.
Total should equal the total of all items in cost. But equals 0;

Comment: What is `Total` before the loop starts? And does the `Costs` array contain `NSDecimalNumber`s?

Comment: Total is 0, costs array contains contents on plist. 
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
 <string>2.60</string>
 <string>1.10</string>
 <string>1.10</string>
 <string>1.10</string>
 <string>1.10</string>
 <string>2.85</string>
 <string>2.85</string>
 <string>1.10</string>
 <string>1.10</string>
 <string>1.10</string>
 <string>1.10</string>
 <string>1.10</string>
 <string>2.85</string>
 <string>2.85</string>
 <string>1.10</string>
 <string>1.10</string>
</array>
</plist>

Comment: This shows the values as strings, not numbers. Where do you convert each string to an `NSDecimalNumber`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic for adding all of the costs in the `Costs` array is a bit strange. Try this:

```
NSDecimalNumber *total = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
for (NSString *cost in Costs) {
    NSDecimalNumber *num = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:cost];
    total = [total decimalNumberByAdding:num];
}

NSLog(@"total = %@", total);
```

BTW - standard naming conventions dictates that classes begin with uppercase letters while methods and variables begin with lowercase letters.

Comment: Code works (sort of) total ends up equaling 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002019549956304625021096371054384448 not 26.10 like it should. any ideas?

Comment: Run the code in the debugger and look at `total` and `cost` in each iteration of the loop. Do you see anything unexpected?

Comment: cost is normal, but total gets smaller and smaller

Comment: Are you sure that each value in the `costs` array is an `NSDecimalNumber`?

Comment: costs array contains contents on plist. 
<plist version="1.0"> <array> <string>2.60</string> <string>1.10</string> <string>1.10</string> <string>1.10</string> <string>1.10</string> <string>2.85</string> <string>2.85</string> <string>1.10</string> <string>1.10</string> <string>1.10</string> <string>1.10</string> <string>1.10</string> <string>2.85</string> <string>2.85</string> <string>1.10</string> <string>1.10</string> </array> </plist>

Comment: That's the problem. The values are strings, not numbers. See my updated answer.